# Can you create an MSI with electron-packager?

Tags: electron, electron-packager

I've just built an app with Electron.

Installing and running `electron-packager .` creates a folder `my-app-win32-x64` with a bunch of assets and DLLs.

This isn't exactly something I can distribute to consumers.

What's the simplest way to generate a Windows installer for my electron executable?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like according to their wiki you can. Follow the instructions here! https://github.com/electron/windows-installer

Answer (score 0):

You may try `electron-wix-msi` it will help you to create a exe file.

it will basically ask you for your source file Path example D:\xyz\my-app-win32-x64
and will create a desired file at app source path.